# Ruby Variables Swap confusion

Tags: ruby, swap

i'm trying to figure out why this swap does not work properly. I added `p` to check the values on repl.it  This is a partition method for a quicksort:

```
def partition (array, from, to)
    #declared pivot to last index of array
    pivot = array[to]
    pIndex = from
    for i in from..to-1
        if array[i] <= pivot
            array[i], array[pIndex] = array[pIndex], array[i]
            pIndex += 1
        end
    end
    p pivot
    p array[to]
    ### why doesn't this work properly?  pivot is same as array[to]
    ### array[pIndex], pivot = pivot, array[pIndex]
    ### the swap below works
    array[pIndex], array[to] = array[to], array[pIndex]
    p array
    return pIndex
end
```

I have a `pivot = array[to]`.  It is then swapped with an array[pIndex]: `array[pIndex], pivot = pivot, array[pIndex]` and `array[pIndex]` value changes to `pivot` but `pivot` did not change to `array[pIndex]`.  But when I do this instead: `array[pIndex], array[to] = array[to], array[pIndex]` it works perfectly find.  Can anyone tell me why?

Example with an array:

`arr = [7, 2, 1, 6, 8, 5, 3, 4]`

`partition(arr, 0,7)`

Before the last swap happens the array is `[2, 1, 3, 6, 8, 5, 7, 4]`.  My last line of swap is suppose to swap `pivot` which is 4, with `array[pIndex]` which is 6. This should change the array to `[2, 1, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 6]`.

Comment: Seeing `for` in Ruby code is very unusual. `(from...to).each do |i|` is more typical Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down what parallel assignment is doing here.

Say we have an array:

```
arr = [1, 2]
arr[0], arr[1] = arr[1], arr[0]
# arr => [2, 1]
```

This is the expected behavior - we are simultaneously doing the following two operations:
`arr[0] = arr[1]` and `arr[1] = arr[0]`.

Now suppose we do

```
arr = [1, 2]
first = arr[0]
first, arr[1] = arr[1], first
# arr => [1, 1]
# first => 2
```

This is because now we are doing `first = arr[1]` and `arr[1] = first`.
`first` is a variable set to the value found at `arr[0]`, and changing this variable does NOT mutate the array.

Comment: smh moment right there... lol.  Well, I'm still in learning phase!  Thanks for clearing that up @Damon

Comment: @hockmode np, everyone has those moments at every skill level :)